# Powershell Remoting from Linux, New-PSSession error

Tags: powershell

Running Kali Linux 2018.2, trying to use Powershell remoting to run commands on Windows from Linux.  Can you help if I'm missing something here?  Is powershell remoting not supported from Linux yet?

Error: New-PSSession : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED

Command: /powershell> New-PSSession -ComputerName Host1 -Credential $cred

$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.0.0-alpha
PSEdition                      Core
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   3.0.0.0
GitCommitId                    v6.0.0-alpha.18
CLRVersion
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3708), use `-HostName` and `-UserName` (instead of `-ComputerName` and `-Credential`). You might need to install OpenSSH-Win32 first

Comment: Hey Robert, do you currently have WinRM setup for implicit remoting? If so how are you authenticating to the service?

Comment: I'll have to confirm these.  Not sure.